# Is a product of semi-algebras a semi-algebra itself?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S_i$ be a semi-algebra on $\Omega_i$.

Is $\{\prod_{i=1}^na_i:a_i\in S_i\}$ always a semi-algebra on $\prod_{i=1}^n\Omega_i$ ?
Yes or No, Why?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.